# Políticas de ElasticBeanstalk faltan

Tags: aws, deployment

Estoy siguiendo [un tutorial sobre cómo desplegar aplicaciones web con AWS](https://youtu.be/ir5qqByo04g?t=4744). Estoy configurando las políticas para un grupo de usuarios pero no encuentro las mismas. Efectivamente parece que tengo que configurar el ElasticBeanstalkService y el ElasticBeanstalkService

[image]

Pero no los habemos aqui:

[image]

Intenté sin elegir ninguna politicas pero me devuelve:

```
Enter Application Name
(default is "mlh-localhost-build-and-deploy-aws-starter"):
ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. User: arn:aws:iam::193798676932:user/lhd-build-aws is not authorized to perform: elasticbeanstalk:CreateAppli
cation on resource: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-3:193798676932:application/mlh-localhost-build-and-deploy-aws-starter
```

## Actualizacion

Finalmente decidí dar los derechos de administrador en Elastic Beanstalk, `AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk` a este usuario:

```
It appears you are using Python. Is this correct?
(Y/n): Y
Select a platform branch.
1) Python 3.8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
2) Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
3) Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux
(default is 1): 1  # <-- Actually I am using Python 3.9

Do you wish to continue with CodeCommit? (Y/n): Y
EB CLI does not have the right permissions to access CodeCommit. List of IAM policies needed by EB CLI, please configure and try again.
 codecommit:CreateRepository
 codecommit:CreateBranch
 codecommit:GetRepository
 codecommit:ListRepositories
 codecommit:ListBranches
To learn more, see Docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/access-permissions.html
ERROR: ServiceError - User: arn:aws:iam::193798676932:user/lhd-build-aws is not authorized to perform: codecommit:ListRepositories
```

Entonces anadi `AWSCodeCommitFullAccess` pero ahora tengo un otro problema:

```
Type a keypair name.
(Default is aws-eb):
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in C:\Users\antoi\.ssh\aws-eb.
Your public key has been saved in C:\Users\antoi\.ssh\aws-eb.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:MdnOmGEkiWUp116mywcRqnVIEZsgGBQmjR8VjFCVCdk aws-eb
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
 Hay cosas aqui
|                 |
|                 |
+----[SHA256]-----+
ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: Efw29Zjkv8doX4V9CHXv
2RibQWKRZ-p5bXK6F-2ktZNb0gydzTdX_CkQ7nYqzf5PDA-UvZZsz9k8V9d-aVvTKaroR6BvfGQ1nxcCrRTmIoUMo_KOlNmd-7eotWe07QGA2-G8dJavD1ZwutQMXH_5T1U_pEZvmTWEyFewwr9C1C5QRgd
J5JnXMJ0K2ndC00FoJlUt2quFaCy-8lUMFRqoCmn0aIWqNWGFmUKiMqFUtOxTPPIic8ANzEknEI82ROeGmA701CXkHOwyv5CpM84h06YEmWH9pi8B5uXyjVSd2fDgYzxKpKrex5J--7FMX6Kj75W7JIN2mD
83wxG24kRLnxbLr-zfEs4InySjfpORLDWoC8BpR4cO2JpScVZ86P1PIWIPLnlxok7lOF4I15muQu78jY1iu31RVgUpcJAyu0phevyOA7oZ5viPe1MRTYTiVgHDbsuiUGCP8bIrIlGN1AoXxtjlwqsxXbgGr
XjRlciIfHCcH5-DNxOpk_6MaGpXEt8Vf98AT0HrsBwRfPB-Kg
```

Aquí debería haber estado más bien conectado con el servidor como en el tutorial:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esas son políticas predefinidas. Puedes crear las tuyas y otorgar o eliminar los permisos que creas pertinentes. Es posible que en alguna actualización de los servicios de AWS las políticas predefinidas hayan sufrido cambios, especialmente si el curso tiene ya un par de años o más

Comment: Gracias, @eferion. Parece que el curso se creó en 2021, así que no es tan antiguo entonces. Sólo estoy buscando las mejores políticas para poder desplegar mi aplicación porque de momento no funciona. Obtengo:  `not authorized to perform: elasticbeanstalk:CreateAppli
cation on resource`

Comment: lo importante es otorgar las menores políticas posibles, con eso limitas la acción de un atacante o un fallo en la aplicación. Lo ideal es dejar que vaya fallando y mirar qué permisos te pide en cada error

Comment: dicho esto, parece que tu usuario no tiene permiso para hacer ciertas tareas